# Unable to redirect requests from one virtual host to another, using Apache RewriteRule

Tags: apache

I have two virtual hosts, served by Apache web server. One host is for PHP application and another one for Django/Python application. Both of them work good and I have no problems with that. At this moment my httpd-vhosts.conf looks like so:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/accent"
    ServerName php.localhost
    <Directory c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/accent>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex 
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName django.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/django/accent/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/django/accent">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's all ok. When I go to `php.localhost`, I see my PHP application and when I go to `django.localhost`, I see my Django application. Nice. But what I want to achive is to redirect requests from my first PHP application, to my Django application, so that whenever there is `/django/` part in the URL, I will be redirected to `django.localhost`. For example, this URL

```
php.localhost:8080/django/
```

should be mapped to

```
django.localhost:8080
```

and this url

```
php.localhost:8080/django/test
```

should be mapped to

```
django.localhost:8080/test
```

I tried to use rewrite rule, but to no avail. This is what I tried:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/accent"
    ServerName php.localhost
   <Directory c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/accent>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex 
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>
    #New lines
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    "^django/(.*)$"  "django.localhost:8080/$1"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName django.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/django/accent/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "c:/Apache24_32/htdocs/django/accent">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, I've added these two lines to the first virtual host description:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    "^django/(.*)$"  "django.localhost:8080/$1"
```

However, it doesn't work. I checked it like so. In my index.php page I added a reference:

```
<a href="/django">Go to Django!</a>
```

But when I click it, I'm redirected to http://php.localhost:8080/django and see this error message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /django was not found on this server.

I'm not that good at configuring Apache and hope someone can help me. Many thanks!

PS

I should add, that this line is uncommented in httpd.conf:

```
 LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VirtualHost context, the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) *Pattern* will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string, so it has the slash at the beggining. This should do:

```
RewriteRule    ^/django/(.*)$  http://django.localhost:8080/$1"
```

Comment: Should I put it inside PHP virtual host definition?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it does not work. I'm still redirected to php.localhost:8080/django and get the very same error.

Comment: Yes, you should put it instead of your RewriteRule in the above .conf. Also, this rule will not match just `/django` (without the trailing slash), try `<a href="/django/">Go to Django!</a>`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, sir! And by the way, if I post to this django address, will those post variables be seen by Django? In other words, can I make a POST request from PHP-application to the Django application?

Comment: It is complicated, read this discussion http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: Oh, it seems like I found a solution to POST from PHP application to a Django application. Firstly, you need to enable mod_proxy and proxy_http_module and then you need to make such a rule: `^/django/(.*)$  http://django.localhost:8080/$1 [NC,P]`. I checked it and it works!

Comment: That will work, but proxying with RewriteRule's [P] flag comes with performance penalty and inability to adjust the URL in the Location headers on HTTP redirect responses. It would be better to use proper `ProxyPass /django/ http://django.localhost:8080/`  and `ProxyPassReverse /django/ http://django.localhost:8080/` directives

Comment: And can I preserve both - GET and POST variables? I'm asking this, because I've just switched from RewriteRule to ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse and see that now only POST variables are preserved. But in real world I would need both

Comment: That should not be the case, how did you observe that?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Everything is ok!